# which thread will get concurrentModificationException with two threads

Tags: java, concurrency

I have two thread one thread is adding,removing in ArrayList and 
another thread iterating with iterator the ArrayList. which thread will get the ConcurrentModificationException;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thread with the iterator. It's the iterator that detects (on a best effort basis) that the underlying collection has changed, and throws the exception.

Of course the most common situation for `ConcurrentModificationException` is when using a single thread that both iterates the collection and attempts to modify it:

```
List<String> foo = ... ;
for(String s : foo) {  // Exception will be thrown here after 1st iteration
    foo.add("Let's throw an exception!");
}
```

Comment: please consider a situation when I am adding and removing on single threaded, is it not throw any exception. if yes then how?

Comment: It only throws one if you modify the collection outside of the iterator.

Comment: you have mention in answer that Iterator detects that exception. but if i dont use iterator then what happens.

Comment: Then nothing happens. Or at least you won't get a `ConcurrentModificationException` (it's thrown by the `Iterator`) .

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be determined for sure. This is from [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html):

> Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast operations throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: ConcurrentModificationException should be used only to detect bugs

Comment: That just describes the fail-fast behaviour of the `Iterator`. It's still always the thread using the iterator which will throw the exception.

Comment: @Kayaman fail-fast behaviour of the `Iterator` is just an example which is given in documentation. It dosn't mean that it only can occur in `Iterator`.

Comment: In this particular question it does. You're free to describe another example.

Comment: @Kayaman essential part of the documentation is this: `impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification` and fail-fast is an example. I agree though that it could be just an `Iterator` in that particular case. But it could be missleading.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. If the exception is thrown, it always comes from the iterating thread. Nothing unclear here. We just can't trust that the iterator will see the change (which is why I provided an easier to understand single threaded example).

Comment: does add remove method in ArrayList check the size or modification of collection while other thread iterate or add.